# A question about dense orbit on $X=\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{0\}$

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions, ergodic-theory

Let $X=\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ be subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric and let $(T, X)$ be a semiflow on $X$, this means that $\varphi:T\times X\to X$ with $\varphi(t, x)= tx$ is a continuous semigroup action. Also, we assume that $p\in X$ does have dense orbit, this means that $\overline{Tp}=X$.

Is it may be happen that  there is $t_0\in T$, $t_0\neq e$,  such that $t_0p=p$?

In the case of $\mathbb{Z}^+$, it is impossible. What can say in other case of semigroups?

Comment: Note that a subset $A$ of $X$ is dense if and only if $A = X$ or $A = \{1/n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Thus, $Tp$ is infinite. In particular, (1) $p$ cannot be a periodic point and (2) $T$ must be infinite.

Comment: @FlorianR Thanks, I know that if $t_0p=p$, then $< t_0 > p=\{p\}$, but it is not clear for me that if $\overline{Tp}=X$, then $\overline{(T-< t_0> )p}=X$?

Comment: You are right, I jumped the gun. I am used to working with $Z=\mathbb{Z}$ or $Z = \mathbb{R}$, but the question is more subtle than I realized. I'll think about it.

Comment: @FlorianR, thanks